# Azure Runbook Fails to Connect - "Confidential Client is not supported in Cross Cloud request."

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, runas

I'm working in a **Azure Gov tenant**. I created an Azure Automation account so I could use it to scale down web apps on the weekend using a **powershell runbook**. I'm using the code below to authenticate the run as account but its failing with this error message: **"Confidential Client is not supported in Cross Cloud request."**

```
$ConnectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"

try
{
    
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $ServicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $ConnectionName         

    # Logging into Azure
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
                -ServicePrincipal `
                -TenantId $ServicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
                -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
                -CertificateThumbprint $ServicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
                -EnvironmentName "AzureUSGovernment"
              

    Write-Output "Successfully logged in to Azure." 
} 
catch
{
    if (!$ServicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $ConnectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } 
    else
    {
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }

}
```

I tried using a different authentication command with newer powershell modules but **I get the same error**:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
$servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName

$logonAttempt = 0
$logonResult = $False

while(!($connectionResult) -And ($logonAttempt -le 10))
{
    $LogonAttempt++
    #Logging in to Azure...
    $connectionResult = Connect-AzAccount `
                           -ServicePrincipal `
                           -Tenant $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
                           -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
                           -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
}
```

Has anybody run this issue before and found a work around? I'm lost and would appreciate any help/assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up working for me, adding the **-Environment** parameter at the end solved my problem:

```
$ConnectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"

try 
{
# Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $ConnectionName

# Logging into Azure
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint -Environment AzureUSGovernment

Write-Output "Successfully logged in to Azure.
```